# TreeMap get first element and remove

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I need to remove and get the first/lowest element from a `TreeMap`. But unles I'm overlooking something there is no way to do this at once.

```
removedValue = treeList.remove(treeList.firstEntry().getValue());
```

That line has to access the map two times but it seems to be the way to go. I don't think it should make much difference since the map gets sorted when something is added but I would expect functionality for it.

Comment: Can't you do `removedValue = treeList.pollFirstEntry().getValue();` ?

Comment: @AlexisC. that should be an answer.

Comment: @AlexisC. does that remove the entry from the list as well?

Comment: @MennoGouw why don't you read the javadoc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#pollFirstEntry%28%29

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah I should have but it just didn't occur to me since I do not associate remove with "poll".

Comment: Anyway, delete post or can the answer be posted?

Comment: @MennoGouw What do you want to happen if the map is empty?

Comment: @PaulBoddington That won't be possible `while (treeList.size > 0)`. And if it would I could check for that. Any other options then?

Comment: No Alexis C's comment is it. If it appears i'll upvote.

Comment: @MennoGouw that wasn't a reaction to your original question. I miss methods from the javadoc often myself. It was a reaction to your comment asking if it removes the entry. That is explicitely written i the javadoc, and once you know what to search for, it's hard to miss.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, should have checked before making that comment ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to both remove and fetch the entry, you can use [`pollFirstEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#pollFirstEntry--) (assuming the type of the variable you're using is at least a `NavigableMap` - but since you're using `firstEntry`, I guess it is).

```
T2 removedValue = null;
Map.Entry<T1, T2> entry = treeList.pollFirstEntry();
if(entry != null) {
    removedValue = entry.getValue();
}
```

Note the `null` check to avoid a NPE if the map is empty (it will return `null` in this case).

Comment: I would use a treeList.isEmpty() check before the poll instead of the null check afterwards to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 I would recommend:

```
Optional<T2> removedValue = Optional.ofNullable(treeList.pollFirstEntry()).map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

This copes well with empty lists as you can then use `removedValue.isPresent()` to check if a value is returned.